# mysql - converting a string column to a date column when parts of date are missing

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I'm working with a table that describes a set of 92 medical publications (name, date_published, citation, source, abstract).

In the original spreadsheet, I wrote the values in date_published as YYYY-MM-DD. However, some of the publications were missing the day-- they just had MM and YYYY. To keep that column's character count consistent for each row, I substituted a missing day with 00 (i.e.: 2014-09-00).

Mysql wasn't okay with the 00 in the DATE datatype and refused to import my csv correctly. So, I changed that column's data type to be VARCHAR, and then it imported everything perfectly.

I want to convert everything in the date_published column from VARCHAR to DATE as it should be. How do I get mysql to treat the 00 day as null, but still interpret month and year correctly?

EDIT: Some of the publications specify the day they were released, but most do not. If they do, I need to record it. If they don't I can't just make up a day (like replacing 00 with 01 to make it a valid YYYY-MM-DD entry). This is for an academic website and they're very particular about the release dates of their research.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Here's the thing. The date datatype will only store VALID dates. As you've seen 00 is not a valid day. So pick a VALID day for the month/year combo and you're good. If you don't want a "day" to display, then add a column which specifies the precision of the date field. Then, when you go to display the date, if the prevision is say "Month" then format the output to exclude the day. such as `date_format(DateField,%M %Y)`  So you get February 2017 and the date character is "hidden".  Use 3 fields and combine adding 1 to dates with 00 and format on output date_format(to_date('2017-02-01'),%M %Y)

Comment: As an alternative use 3 date fields and display those fields which are populated.  So 2017 in some cases where no month, day are listed, September 2016 for some without days listed and 28 September 2016 for those with dates listed; but then you lose date validations.  IMO this is the only way to do this if the database could be directly accessible by others in which they could query and bypass your date format.  If they can only inquire though PHP, then you have total control and adding 01 to a date and formatting it would work fine.

Comment: Thanks @xQbert, this comment solves my problem in a more elegant way than what I was trying to do. I wish I could mark your comment as the answer so you could get points.

Comment: I'm not after the points and my comments are an approach not a ultimate answer.  I would recommend commenting what you do in an answer and accepting it; provided the ones below do not address your specific need.  As what you do may help others!  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the 0 direct with the import like this:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'my.csv'
INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(id, column2, column3, @mydate) -- read one of the field to variable
SET mydate = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@mydate, '-', 2),'-', 
GREATEST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@mydate, '-', -1),1)), '%Y-%m-%e');
```

**sample**

**the csv**

```
$ cat my.csv
1,foo,'bar,2017-01-00
2,foo2,'bar2,2016-04-12
3,foo,'bar,2015-08-00
```

**the Import**

```
mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'my.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> (id, column2, column3, @mydate) -- read one of the field to variable
    -> SET mydate = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@mydate, '-', 2),'-',
    -> GREATEST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@mydate, '-', -1),1)), '%Y-%m-%e');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0,00 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM table_name;
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
| id | column2 | column3 | mydate              |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
|  1 | foo     | 'bar    | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |
|  2 | foo2    | 'bar2   | 2016-04-12 00:00:00 |
|  3 | foo     | 'bar    | 2015-08-01 00:00:00 |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

**sample 2 with a extra column**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM table_name;
Empty set (0,00 sec)

mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE 'my.csv'
    -> INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME
    -> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    -> LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    -> (id, column2, column3, @mydate) -- read one of the field to variable
    -> SET haveDay = IF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@mydate, '-', -1) = 0 , 0 ,1),
    ->
    -> mydate = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@mydate, '-', 2),'-',
    -> GREATEST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@mydate, '-', -1),1)), '%Y-%m-%e');
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0,01 sec)
Records: 3  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM table_name;
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+---------+
| id | column2 | column3 | mydate              | haveDay |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+---------+
|  1 | foo     | 'bar    | 2017-01-01 00:00:00 |       0 |
|  2 | foo2    | 'bar2   | 2016-04-12 00:00:00 |       1 |
|  3 | foo     | 'bar    | 2015-08-01 00:00:00 |       0 |
+----+---------+---------+---------------------+---------+
3 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: except that the question indicates the OP doesn't want to have a date at all. Putting 01 on the date is improper per League14's first comment on Ken's answer; but Aaron's response of adding an extra column is along the right track imo.

Comment: @xQbert - yes i have add a sample with a extra column for you. that will also direct filled by the import.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL won't interpret the date correctly like this, instead replace 00 with 01.
example; 2014-09-01

Comment: Unfortunately I can't just replace the 00 with any other acceptable date integer, since that would be fraud when it comes to these publications. It's extremely important to accurately show when this research was released. Is there a way I can register the 00 as null?

Comment: @League14 How on earth can it possibly be *more* accurate to state that research happened on the 0th day of a month? Sounds like you either need to add an extra column that indicates when a date is "approximate" or you need to stop using the right data type.

Comment: @AaronBertrand it's not more accurate by any means. That's why I'm trying to get the day to be null (instead of 00 or 01) for the entries that are missing a day.

Comment: @League14 I get it, but a day can't be NULL or 0, so you need to do something else, as I suggested.

Comment: You can do it direct change it with **LOAD DATA ...**. see my Answer

Comment: The only other thing I could suggest is splitting the date up into 3 different fields in the database, one for each; Y/M/D. Then you can combine then for searching.